# What data should be returned to Adobe Reader for PDF Form submit via PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, pdf, reader

We have a bunch of fillable PDFs that need to be submitted to various email addresses depending on their purpose and location.  Each PDF has a 'Submit' button that directs the document to a PHP script on our server that saves the completed PDF as the entire PDF document and emails the PDF as an attachment to what ever email address is specified in the URL.

That is all working fine.

The problem is I cannot, for the life of me, figure out or find what needs to be returned to the PDF (using Adobe Reader) for user feedback.  IE- an alert box that says 'Your form was successfully submitted' or something similar.  The script executes successfully but I keep getting an error in Reader that says,

**"An error occurred during the submit process. Cannot process content of type text/html."**

Here's my PHP so far.  Everything commented out at the bottom represents something I've tried already and it hasn't worked:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$file = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$time = microtime(true);
$newfile = "forms/" . $time . ".pdf";  
$worked = file_put_contents($newfile, $file); 
ob_end_clean();

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSendmail();
$mail->setFrom('emailAddress', 'emailName');
$mail->addReplyTo('emailAddress', 'emailName');
$mail->addAddress($_REQUEST['email']); 
$mail->addAttachment( $newfile );
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'New form submission';
$mail->Body    = 'A new form has been submitted.';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    //return false;
    //echo "Message could not be sent:  ";
    //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    //header('Content-type: text/html');
    //echo 'Form successfully submitted';

    //header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    //@readfile($newfile);

    //echo 'Message has been sent';

    //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    //return true;

    //header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    //echo 'app.alert("Form emailed successfully",3);';

    //@readfile('success.pdf');

    //header('location: success.pdf');
    //header('Location: success.pdf');
    //header(location: success.html');
}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

**NOTE:** `@readfile($newfile)` DID return the PDF back to Reader without an error message but I don't want that- I just want a simple text alert of some kind.

Comment: Obviously you can't send HTML to a PDF viewer. You have the following options: return a full PDF, return an FDF file, return an XFDF file. Given the fact that you may not have a PDF library in your PHP stack, I suggest that you return an XFDF file. An XFDF file is an XML file. If you want to know what an XFDF file looks like, take a look at [How to save an .xfdf file as a .pdf file?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-save-xfdf-file-pdf-file)

Comment: I'll check that out after my meetings, thanks!

Comment: One question: why does `@readfile($newfile)` return the filled PDF but `@readfile('success.pdf')` does not return a simple 'Success!' PDF I created?

Comment: I think that your server returns a 500 message in HTML, for instance because the server can't find `success.pdf` (e.g. because the path to the file is incorrect).

Comment: Remove the @-sign and check your error logs. Additionally do not forget to send the content-type header, too!

Comment: @Setasign: That got the success pdf to load.  Thanks!  For the short term that's how we're going to go but I'll def check out XFDF for more robust functions for version 2 of all this.  Thanks for the tip, Bruno!

Answer (score 3):

I use this code in my PHP-based PDF form processor. It writes a FDF response that Adobe Reader understands. Adobe Reader displays the thank you message after the form is submitted. If the form is submitted from a web page (say for troubleshooting), the PHP script lists the form fields submitted.

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'AcroForms') {
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.fdf');
    echo "%FDF-1.2\r\n" .
         "1 0 obj<< /FDF << /Status (Thank you and good bye.) >>      >>endobj\r\n" .
         "trailer\r\n" .
         "<< /Root 1 0 R >>%%EOF";
} else {
    foreach ($_POST as $ffield => $fvalue) {
        echo "$ffield = " . "$fvalue<br />";
    }   
}?>
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Thank you so much.  I knew I was missing something simple.  In this case the header and the full obj code.  Part of the problem of working on 6 different projects simultaneously...  don't have the time to fully trouble-shoot.  Thanks again.

Comment: I got this code from another SOF member. Unfortunately, I don't have the reference.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for newer versions of Acrobat DC. I instead just returned a plain old string and it seems to display fine.